# Messy text formatting in Ubuntu console

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal

My ubuntu terminal shows tables in bad order. I played with settings, changed font size and clicked everything but didn't help. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line is just too large to be seen on just one line, so it wraps. You can "pipe" the command through less (sudo docker container ls -a | less) and press right arrow on your keyboard. But (IMHO) this is not practical for dailly use. Eventually you'll just get used to this output behaviour.

Comment: Is there a way to make it look like a table? Like a border or something